# Best performance method to check if contentState changed in DraftJS, or just editorState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I'm trying to have a function run only when the contentState itself has changed, not just the editorState.

My idea right now would be to store the old contentState as a string and compare it to the new contentState as a string, but this seems awfully wasteful to be converting states to strings and comparing them. Is there a better way?

Comment: if you share the comparing code we can help in more details if my answer doesn't help you much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can simply compare the value of your `old state` and the value of your `new state` you don't have to `convert` it to `string`.

EDIT: and here is a concept about react `state` that you don't have worry about a `large state object` as best practices recommend to do that way

> Common misconception: `state` is held in a `large object`. It’s just object referencing a few other objects. Nothing large about it.

Comment: Fair point, but it still seems wasteful to compare this relatively large object on every click, key press, etc. Am I overthinking this?

I know one little thing like this isn't going to kill performance, but it seems very wasteful. Is this the least wasteful way?

Comment: it's ok to compare them on such case as you mention for a `large object` when there is no easy way around to `update` them with a `new state`.

Comment: Note that since they are immutable objects, the comparison is quick to do. It's comparing identity, not contents. That is, `this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent() === newEditorState.getCurrentContent()`

Comment: This doesn't work if you want to exclude changes to selection state, and just want to compare content state (blocks and entities)

Answer (score 0):

I have used another approach for checking whether the Editor content has changed or not.

Basically I am making use of an npm module [deep-equal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-equal) to compare raw contentState objects (i.e contentState converted to simple JS object using convertToRaw function). 
In your onChange handler, compare the old and new raw contentState objects.

Note: Comparison by deep-equal module is around 5 times faster than wrapping node's assert.deepEqual() in a try/catch.

Here is the onChange handler code:

```
const deepEqual = require('deep-equal');

this.onChange = (editorState) => {

    let oldContent = convertToRaw(this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent());
    let newContent = convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent());

    let sameContent = deepEqual(oldContent, newContent);

    this.setState({editorState});

    if (sameContent === false)
      console.log('Content has changed.');
}
```

Comment: It's a lot more expensive than just checking a reference equality as suggested by the most upvoted answer.

Comment: This is the only way if you only want to take content (blocks/entities) into account.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so different from Faisal Mushtaq's answer, but includes a few improvements. In your component's `constructor`:

```
// keep track of the last state
let lastContentState = this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent()

this.onChange = editorState => {
  this.setState({ editorState })

  // push your handling code onto the call stack with a setTimeout
  // so that it doesn't block handling new inputs to the editor
  setTimeout(() => {

    // first-time focus or blur, no change to content
    if (!editorState.getLastChangeType()) return

    const currentContentState = editorState.getCurrentContent()

    // ES6 to compare, could use Immutable.is() instead
    const toHandle = !Object.is(lastContentState, currentContentState)

    if (toHandle) {
      // your handler function, eg passed in as a prop
      this.props.handleChange(currentContent)

      // current content becomes last content
      lastContentState = currentContentState
    }

  }, 0)
}
```